# new Date().toLocaleTimeString doesn't work correctly

Tags: reactjs, date, input, time

There is a problem with `new Date().toLocaleTimeString()` between 23:59:59 and 01:00:00

```
const currentTimeString = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
  hour12: false
});

const MyComponent= ({curr}) => {
    const [time, setTime] = useState({
      start: "00:00:00",
      end: curr
  });

     useEffect(() => {
        getResults(time.start, time.end)

    );
  }, [time]);
   const handleChangeTime = e => {
    
    setTime({ ...time, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
   };

return(<>
        <input
            type="time"
            name="start"
            onChange={handleChangeTime}
            value={time.start}
            placeholder="00:00:00"
            step={10}              
        /> 
      </>)


}
```

After **23:59:59** I get time in state like **24:00:00** and time input works like this before 01:00:00 (ex. **instead of 00:53:45 it shows 24:53:45**)

after 01:00:00 it works correctly. How can I fix this problem?
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `en-US`, you can use `en-GB`(British English), and by default it's in 24-hour format:

```js
const time = new Date('2020/09/02 00:24:36');

console.log(time.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB'));
```